# Adding Images to a video in iOS

Tags: ios, video, uiimage, avfoundation, avassetexportsession

I am working on a video app, which allows merging of clips selected from the camera roll. However, the user is also allowed to include images. If a user selects an image along with clips, this image should be a part of video with the playback time of five seconds(suppose user selects a video of 10 seconds, an image and another video of 20 seconds, then the final video should be of 35 seconds with image being a part of video). How can i do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can decode the Video Frames and add your image after the particular frame and then encode it again.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332807/decode-video-frames-on-iphone-gpu/9450056#9450056

Comment: Also you can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267629/how-do-i-add-a-still-image-to-an-avcomposition